# pandas df - interpolate value in column A for an interpolated value in column B

Tags: python, pandas, interpolation

given this dataframe

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'RATIO': [1, .8, .6, .3, .2, 0],
    'VALUE': [100, 75, 55, 45, 35, 25]
})
print (df)
```

```
    RATIO  VALUE
0    1.0    100
1    0.8     75
2    0.6     55
3    0.3     45
4    0.2     35
5    0.0     25
```

what is the most efficient way to interpolate a VALUE column value for an interpolated RATIO column value of .75?

must I set the index to RATIO, then reindex, adding .75 to the index, then sort, then interpolate (as shown below?)  or is there a more convenient approach?

thank you.

```
df = df.set_index('RATIO')
df = df.reindex(df.index.values.tolist() + [.75])
df = df.sort_index(ascending=False)
df['VALUE'] = df['VALUE'].interpolate(method='linear')
print (df)
```

```
       VALUE
RATIO       
1.00   100.0
0.80    75.0
0.75    65.0
0.60    55.0
0.30    45.0
0.20    35.0
0.00    25.0
```

h/t to @dermen, worth noting that depending on desired output value, might pass interpolate method='index' as opposed to method='linear' as i did above

```
df['VALUE'] = df['VALUE'].interpolate(method='index')
```

Comment: `np.interp(.7,5 df['RATIO'], df['VALUE'])` but the data need to be increasing/decreasing by `RATIO`.

Comment: Isnt the desired value 70 (for linear interpolation) ?

Answer (score 1):

Note, your proposed method is actually incorrect, you need to set `method='index'`, otherwise the values are treated as evenly spaced (as per the [df.interpolate documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html))

In any case, I would simple use scipy directly as its compatible with Series:

```py
import pandas
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

df = pandas.DataFrame({
    'RATIO': [1, .8, .6, .3, .2, 0],
    'VALUE': [100, 75, 55, 45, 35, 25]
})

val = interp1d(df.RATIO, df.VALUE, bounds_error=False, fill_value=np.nan, kind='linear')(0.75)
print(val)
# 70
```

Note, there's no sorting required for this approach...